# Problema em herança com HIBERNATE

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, hibernate, herança

Pois bem, meu problema é o seguinte, Tenho uma classe abstrata **Funcionário** e duas subclasses **Atendente** e **Dentista** que herdam de funcionário.

Tenho também uma classe **Usuário**, que tem como atributos login, ... , .... , ... e um funcionário vinculado a ela.

Minha ideia é que quando por exemplo fossemos cadastrar um usuário fosse informado também um funcionário que estaria vinculado a ele. Porém como foi dito, a classe funcionário é abstrata e pode ser tanto atendente como dentista. Como eu poderia resolver isso?

```
private Funcionario funcionario;

public Usuario(){

}
```

Pensei então em instanciar o funcionário na classe usuário, e receber um parâmetro no construtor que diria se o funcionário é um atendente ou dentista. Isso funcionou, porém me deu outro problema.
Como estou usando o hibernate, quando fiz um select para preencher os dados do usuario e também do respectivo funcionario a consulta deu NullPointerExcpetion por eu não ter feito por exemplo:

```
private Funcionario funcionario;

public Usuario(){
    this.funcionario = new Funcionario();
}
```

Então estou nesse problema atualmente, é um conceito até meio que inicial de OO porém nunca tinha feito algo assim por isso os problemas, alguém pode me ajudar nessa? Obrigado galera!

Answer (score 2):

Creio que a implementação dependerá muito do tipo do projeto. Recomendo uma leitura bem didática do [JPA Mini Book](http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-livro-primeiros-passos-e-conceitos-detalhados/).Estou usando no exemplo abaixo a estratégia Single Table:

Classe Funcionário:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="funcionario")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Funcionario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

}
```

Classe Dentista:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="D")
public class Dentista extends Funcionario {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="registro")
    private String registro;

}
```

Classe Atendente:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="A")
public class Atendente extends Funcionario {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="turno")
    private String turno;

}
```

Classe Usuário (aqui ocorre o mapeamento - nesse caso, creio que seja OneToOne):

```
@Entity
public class Usuario {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "funcionario")
    private Funcionario funcionario;

    public Usuario(Dentista dentista) {
        this.funcionario = dentista;
    }

    public Usuario(Atendente atendente) {
        this.funcionario = atendente;
    }

}
```

Comment: Só uma observação: Se a coluna no banco for o mesmo nome do atributo, não precisa usar o `name` do `@Column`

Comment: Bem lembrado! Valeu Douglas.